# .Net 6.0 32-bit application and LargeAddressAware flag

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, 32-bit

I have a VS build which is constrained to be 32-bit (by dependencies) and I want to make sure the application is LargeAddressAware.

The application is written .NET 6.0 C# (WPF) and is targetting .NET 6.0. What previously would have been built as the *.exe is now built as a *.dll and a host/shim *.exe created by VS automatically.

Is this host/shim *.exe LargeAddressAware at all?

Do I still need to make host/shim *.exe LargeAddressAware manually?

Comment: Are you sure "LargeAddressAware" is the right approach? It seem like a dangerous thing to do without knowing about all the dlls the runtime might load. A workaround for legacy 32 bit code is to put it in its own process, allowing the majority of the code to run in 64-bit.

Comment: This is my other option, I am trying to avoid this at the moment

Comment: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/LargeAddressAware

Comment: Thanks , already found this from another SO post, the author of the package does not bel;ieve this will work with .NET 6.0